# Key error with scatterplot (matplotlib)(python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a data frame

```
    artist  bpm nrgy    dnce    dB  live    spch    val acous
20  drake   112.0   26.0    49.0    -17.0   7.0 9.0 31.0    65.0
35  drake   100.0   41.0    77.0    -7.0    7.0 10.0    29.0    0.0
36  drake   152.0   57.0    64.0    -7.0    9.0 11.0    43.0    37.0
37  drake   122.0   52.0    63.0    -10.0   9.0 27.0    30.0    3.0
47  drake   172.0   57.0    75.0    -8.0    53.0    48.0    55.0    38.0
48  drake   100.0   24.0    70.0    -9.0    11.0    5.0 38.0    62.0
```

I am trying to create a scatter plot but I keep running into issues with the key. Please help, thank you!

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 18))

current = 1
for col in columns:
    plt.subplot(5, 2, current) # 5 rows, 2 histograms per row
    current += 1 # looping over to the next measure
    plt.plot(df_artist.index, df_artist[col], data=df_artist, linestyle='none', marker='o') 
    plt.title(col)

plt.show()
```

I keep getting a Key error and an empty plot :(

Thank you!

Comment: I know that the type of plot is not important here but, you mention you want a scatter plot but you use plt.plot . matplotlib has 'plt.scatte' is specialized for making scatter plots. And then in the comments, you say histogram. so I suggest you fix it not to become confusing. By the way have you tried to change 'columns' in your for loop to 'df_artist.columns' to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want scatterplots using plot (and not histograms)

Your code has to be in this way

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 18))

current = 1
for col in df.columns:
    plt.subplot(5, 2, current) # 5 rows, 2 histograms per row
    current += 1 # looping over to the next measure
    df_x = np.array(df.index)
    df_y = np.array(df[col])
    plt.plot(df_x, df_y, linestyle='none', marker='o') 
    plt.title(col)

plt.show()
```

**Why is your not code working?**

The reason you were getting key error is because your `df.index` is a list which is mutable and mutable objects cannot be hashed. Therefore you get the error.

**Why the new code works?**

I simply converted the list of values to numpy array which contain int/str values and hence not mutable. Therefore it accepts the values to plot

**Output**

[image]

[image]